# using jquery to change a row in a table

Tags: jquery

Using Javascript, I'm trying to change the class of the first TD of a table row.  Using a button which appears in the same row.  what do I add before the "addClass" to make it only target only the row its in, and the first table data of that row?

```
$("table").on("click", ".checkbox", function() {
 .addClass("line");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use **$(this)** and  **.closest()** to get the parent row .. and **.find()** to get the td  and use **:first** to select first one

```
$("table").on("click", ".checkbox", function() {
   $(this).closest('tr').find('> td:first').addClass("line");
});
```

or you can use **.first()**

```
$("table").on("click", ".checkbox", function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('> td').first().addClass("line");
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help sir.  I was but 3 points away from being able to give your answer an upvote, yet sadly I'm now 5 points away.  All I can offer is my gratitude.

Comment: wait, it's  a miracle, I'm now up to 17!  Huzzah!

Comment: @EliezerWohl able right now :) .. Very good luck to you :) .. Don't tell anyone that I upvoted you :) :) lol

Answer (score 0):

Eliezer -

You are going to want to set a class for the button you are applying the click handler to. That way you can call the selector for all of those buttons. Then you will use the parent calls to get the TD that the button belongs to. It should look something like this:

```
$('.button-class').on('click', function() {
    $(this).parent.addClass('new-class');
});
```